# Google cloud storage bucket size or objects count monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-storage, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I created a policy in stackdriver to be alerted when the size of a Google Storage bucket increases.

it contains only one condition : `Violates when: storage.googleapis.com/storage/total_bytes is above a threshold of 1 for greater than 2 minutes`

> What I noticed that it takes several hours to detect that files are
>   deleted/added to the bucket, what I expected that it takes few seconds
>   ( same as other metrics for example PubSub subscription monitoring )
>   to detect the the bucket size is increased/decreased.

I also used metric storage.googleapis.com/storage/object_count and got almost the same results.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stackdriver size measurements for Google Cloud Storage are updated daily. We will update the documentation to make this more clear.

Comment: I opened a case with Google support (after I got no responses here ), and per his reply that it should update immediately without any delays.
Now I'm confused between your and his reply.

Comment: It has been 24+ hours, but still it hasn't detected that the bucket size has decreased ( empty actually )

Comment: sami - can you please forward the email you exchanged with Google support to me at gs-team@google.com? Please mention my name so it gets routed to me.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your help.

Forwarded it to you.
Note that the case contained several other comments/replies, I forwarded only the first email.

Comment: Have you received the email ?

Comment: Yes, and I let the Google support person know that his response was incorrect.